# Почему Popup открывается под другим Popup?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, popup, всплывающее-окно

Имеется ситуация: с главной формы открывается первый popup (картинка #1). После этого на нём при двойном клике открывается второй popup (картинка #2).
Однако, он открывается не сверху, а под первым popup. 
Второй popup - купленная библиотека, откуда вызывается, - не ясно. 
Первый popup - самописный и его можно изменить.
Код предоставить не могу по причине того, что не ясно что предоставить.

Вопрос: какое свойство отвечает за такое расположение окон и как можно выстроить popup'ы в правильной последовательности?

---

*Картинка #1*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Картинка #2*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте поставить z-index в css

Comment: @MasterAlex да, у второго поп-апа был выставлен z-index меньше, чем у первого